# The camera is like in "Enter The Gungeon"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, cinemachine

I need to create a camera that will follow the mouse while moving parallel to the character, to solve this problem I wrote this code but the camera flies away

```
public class cam : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private Vector2 MousePos;
        [SerializeField] public CinemachineVirtualCamera virtualCamera;
        void Update()
        {
            MousePos = Input.mousePosition;
            CinemachineComponentBase componentBase = virtualCamera.GetCinemachineComponent(CinemachineCore.Stage.Body);
            if (componentBase is CinemachineFramingTransposer)
            {
                (componentBase as CinemachineFramingTransposer).m_ScreenX = -MousePos.x / 999;
                (componentBase as CinemachineFramingTransposer).m_ScreenY = -MousePos.y / 999;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this doesn't work, I haven't tested it.

You could try getting the previous mouse position and calculating the difference to add. Make sure you get the previous mouse position and store it, that way you can calculate the difference this frame.

Something like this:

```
Vector2 MouseDif;
Vector2 DeltaMouse = Vector2.zero;
void Update()
{
     MouseDif = Input.mousePosition - DeltaMouse;//renamed from MousePos
     //The rest of the code
     DeltaMouse = Input.mousePosition;
}
```